# Which of these 2 shuffle roundhouse kicks is preferrable?

Tags: kicking, muay-thai, kickboxing

My lifestyle these days don't allow me to train in a club, but I do try to recall drills from college kickboxing class.  I recall 2 ways of doing the shuffle roundhouse.  I'm trying to choose the right one to fit into a combination.

Assume an orthodox stance.  After a jab and a cross, the front left leg gets shuffled to be come the back leg (for an instant) so that it can throw a powerful roundhouse.  The two ways that I recall shuffling the left leg back are:

(1) *Slide* the left foot back to approximately the level of the right foot, or maybe a bit behind it, then step forward with the right foot.  The left foot is now well behind, and immediately throws a roundhouse.  I guess the stepping forward of the right leg generates power.

(2) Just hop into a southpaw stance and bounce the rear left leg into a roundhouse.

Ideally, one would practice [many different variations of a shuffle roundhouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6R0_IXoDro), but if time is lacking, which one would be better to favour in drills?

Comment: We don't "hop" when throwing the switch kick, we shuffle really quick. The space between your feet and the floor - while shuffling - is only enough for a sheet of paper to fit in. "Hop" means you are doing it too slow and are likely to get countered by a cross - which is always the first courter for a switch kick.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  Why a cross as a counter instead of a jab (possibly leading to a cross)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are training for explosive power, I'd prefer the shuffle step, the second one, as it's a more dynamic move with more sudden movement. Of course, if you're having trouble controlling the roundhouse afterwards, you may want to use the first movement as it's easier to do slowly until you can get a consistent smoothness. Also, if you're unstable after the switch, you might practice just the switch, each time to ensure you're landing in a stable position.

Comment: I find that the step in the 1st option (either forward, rightward, or some direction in between) generates a lot of power also.  Your answer has a lot of "if"s, which reflects the complexity of the situation.  I will try to find a way to do both without doing either so little that it becomes more confusing to muscle memory than it helps.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2153235: If my answer helped, I'm glad. :) But don't feel pressured to accept it, of course, and you are always free to change which answer is accepted by clicking on the checkmarks again.

Comment: Thanks for your openness.  I thinks it's a valid answer because it explains the various possibilities.  The reality is that it is a complicated situation.