# Step in direction of roundhouse kick to inner thigh?

Tags: kicking, muay-thai, kickboxing

From college kickboxing class, I'm trying to recall the details of the lead roundhouse kick to an opponent's inner thigh.  Assuming orthodox stance for both people, it would be a lead round-house to the opponent's lead inner thigh.  However, I'm specifically considering the case where this is thrown after a jab and a cross.  The lead left foot is loaded up for the round house, which would be swinging rightward.

Is it better to step to the right to generate more momentum, or would that *typically* be too slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it better to step to the right to generate more momentum, or would that typically be too slow?

For purposes of easing exposition, I will use *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse* (= no stepping to the right) and *step-right-lead-roundhouse* (= step to the right with your right leg and kick with the left leg) to differentiate between the two.

#### Context is King!

There is no way to tell whether one is better than the other without taking into consideration what your opponent is doing while you are kicking. There is always a trade-off. You **must** think about the effectiveness of a given strike/move by factoring in how your opponent might react.

What if you stepped to your right to generate more momentum for the lead inside roundhouse, but your opponent actually beat you to it and shuffled (or switched stance) to his right? This means you would fail to make any contact with his lead leg, and your momentum would carry through, making you off-balance. The momentum of your *step-right-lead-roundhouse* would open your back to your opponent who will be in the perfect spot for his power shots!

The *step-right-lead-roundhouse* is more powerful than the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*. But the latter is faster. An additional advantage of the *step-right-lead-roundhouse* (besides power) is that it pushes your head much to the right, meaning that your head will now be outside the center line of fire. And this is a great way to not get countered by the Cross or the Overhand Right.

---

#### When to use the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*?

First, here are some reasons to use the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*:

- It's a quick snappy kick to the inside leg.
- Takes minimal effort and energy.
- Does not require swinging of lead arm to generate momentum - because
  "being powerful" is not the purpose of this kick.
- Does not require turning of the upper body like a fully committed switch kick.

Here are some situations when you should use the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*:

**1. Use it to test the waters.** Does he bring his leg up to check your kick? Does he bounce back to avoid it? Does it throw a counter kick or a punch? His reaction gives you an idea about what to expect from him when you actually throw the more powerful, fully committed, *step-right-lead-roundhouse*.

**2. Use it when your opponent takes a step with his lead leg towards you.** This will annoy him to his core. It will prevent him from getting into proper position to throw his combos.

**3. Use it when your opponent throws a Jab-Cross combo.** The Jab might graze your face, but if you land the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse* to the inside of your opponents lead leg, your strike and his momentum from the Cross (which requires one to put weight on the lead leg) will throw him off this balance and open him to your follow-ups.

**4. Use it if your opponent has good footwork and is able to move quickly.** Since the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse* does not require much energy, effort, momentum, or upper-body commitment, you can expect to throw it and quickly move out of the exchange. Use it like an *in-and-out Jab*.

---

#### When to use the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*?

Here are some reasons to use the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*:

- It's more powerful than the *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*, because you put momentum and weight behind the kick.
- If landed in succession, the kicks can severely impair movement and cause instability in the lead leg; it will be hard for your opponent to actually plant his lead foot and throw the rear-legged power roundhouse effectively.
- When you step to the right for the kick, you also effectively get your head out of the center line of fire. This protects you from any counter straight punches.
- Stepping to the side to throw the kick also means you are *kicking through your opponent's leg*; naturally, any strike thrown to go past the target will hurt more than snappy strikes.

Here are some situations when you should use the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*:

**1. Use it when your opponent has his hands up high guarding/covering his face.** Most of the time, when someone covers up with both hands, they are bracing themselves for impact, or they are coming forward with a traditional Muay Thai march (trying to close the gap for clinching). They are heavy on their legs. It is difficult to move around, react to strikes, or step to the sides when both hands are up high covering the face. When you see this happen, use the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*. Destroy that lead leg. It is hard to throw proper, effective counter shots from a guard position.

**2. Use it when your opponent is backing down or stuck in the corner.** When you see your opponent moving back (e.g., say, after a teep or a body shot), use the space, close the space with a step to the right, and throw the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*. You will be in perfect position to generate the most momentum and power behind that kick.

**3. Use it when your opponent is tired and is unlikely to be able to move quickly to avoid it.**

**4. [Advanced] Use it when your opponent throws a rear-legged body or head roundhouse kick.** The key to this is to be good at spotting and reacting. When you see your opponent take a step to the left with their lead leg, chances are he is throwing a rear-legged-roundhouse-kick. If you are able to time this correctly, your *step-right-lead-roundhouse* will be a destructive counter. You will not only cause damage by kicking the standing/supporting/pivoting lead leg, but also move your head and body out of the way to avoid or reduce impact of his rear-legged-roundhouse-kick. Watch the demonstration here: [Inside leg kick techniques](https://youtu.be/nP6DN2h2XNI?t=39). Here is something similar; the stances are different, but you get the idea: [Fedor Emelianenko vs Mirko Cro Cop](https://youtu.be/imHajzoVNDU?t=161).

---

#### Jab + Cross + Inside Leg Kick: Which one and when?

Everything I mentioned above applies here. Your Jab + Cross, if thrown effectively a few times, will most surely warrant respect from the opponent. This means when you throw the Jab + Cross, he will cover up or parry (if he doesn't slip the punches or move out). This is a good time to throw the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*. He will be heavy on his legs, focusing on your straight punches, and this gives you a good opportunity to land the kick with some momentum. Your punches don't have to be strong, they are there just to occupy your opponents hands and get them to brace for the shots, which makes it easier to kick their lead leg. Also note that you can take your step to the right at the same time as the Cross. This will make this technique faster than if you were to bring back the Cross and then stepped to your right. Since the Cross is not the weapon in this technique, you don't have to throw it with commitment. So throw the Jab, and when you throw the Cross, step to the right at the same time.

Your Jab + Cross might also drive them back, which is even better because you can now take a slightly longer right-step and release the *step-right-lead-roundhouse* with more momentum and power.

If your opponent simultaneously throws his punches when you throw your Jab + Cross, or if he slips your punches to the left to throw his left hooks, use the faster *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse*. This will instantly throw them off-balance and give you the time to follow up. Throwing the *step-right-lead-roundhouse* will work against you in this situation. He is slipping your punches to his left, closing the distance with a forward left step while slipping, and throwing the left hook. If you throw the *step-right-lead-roundhouse*, you will be much closer to your opponent and will risk getting badly hit by his left hook. Even if you both connect, his is the strike that will decide the round.

---

#### Note:

I was taught three ways to do the inside leg kick. These are as follows, starting with the quickest and least strong to the slowest and most strong. Note that the difference in speed is actually very small.

1. *basic-lead-snap-roundhouse* - as discussed above.
2. *slide-rear-leg-forward-lead-roundhouse* - see 3rd kick in video below.
3. *step-right-lead-roundhouse* - as discussed above.

The difference between 2 and 3 is that in *slide-rear-leg-forward-lead-roundhouse* you don't step to the right with your back leg, but you slide your back leg forward while simultaneously throwing the lead roundhouse. This is faster and more powerful than 3.

See this video - [Joseph Valtellini Inside Low Kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yqb3lwnRBz4&ab_channel=JosephValtellini) - for the *slide-rear-leg-forward-lead-roundhouse*. I never did the 2nd variation Joe shows.

Comment: Lots of great information there!  I especially like the point about rotating too far with a missed kick and leaving your back exposed.  That's one reason it's so important to stay relaxed during a fight - it lets you commit as late as possible - when you're confident your opponent will still be there when your kick arrives.

Comment: Thanks, RoundHouse.  This is an extensive exposition, so I'm going to have to reserve it for evening reading.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again, RoundHouse.  I had a chance to parse the information.  Very helpful.  The #2 helps sort out [another question I had](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/which-of-these-2-shuffle-roundhouse-kicks-is-preferrable) about shuffling roundhouses in general, especially with the way in which it is demo'd in the video.

Comment: @Unknown I'd prefer the site specific chatroom.

Answer (score 3):

Especially given you're having to rotate back from the cross, I think that the extra step is, indeed, generally too much. It, of course, may be useful if you need a little extra distance, or a pause to throw off your opponent's timing.

Comment: Thanks, @Macaco Branco.  I find that it takes more discipline to not step, so I'll work on that.  This will help me apportion the time spent on each one.

Answer (score 3):

After the jab-cross, I'd almost always throw another jab as I rotate back, and if the distances are all fine as is, kick without moving the back foot.

If you've shifted the front foot across to make room for the back hip to rotate through to power the cross, then you'll tend to be inside the line of their front foot (so if they lifted that foot straight up they can't just front-kick you - they'll need to swivel their hips and front foot towards you before or during their front-leg roundhouse - either way it'll be more telegraphed and easier to defend against.  Anyway - if they haven't been driven back and moved their front leg during your jab-cross[-jab], then your front-leg roundhouse will be kicking into the fleshy side or underside of their front leg.  That can be less conditioned in some people, and disrupts their balance.

On the other hand, if you do shift the back foot forward and to the right - across the line of their front foot, they can quickly lift that front foot and snap out a front kick.  Your groin is exposed - whether they target it deliberately or accidentally.  If you then kick, you'll have a slightly more awkward angle to kick from - takes more time and care to lift your leg higher and bring it down powerfully into their thigh.  Still, kicking down into the top of their thigh means their leg isn't just lifted and pushed sideways - the full force of the kick has to be absorbed into the muscle, but the kicks likely to still be considerably weaker, riskier and slower over-all than a jab-cross with a back-leg roundhouse kick to the top of the thigh, though if they're blocking those it's not a bad idea to mix it up with a front leg kick or something else.

There's another situation when you'd step the back foot, and that's when you're chasing slightly and want to step the back foot in closer to the front foot before delivering your kick.  That way, you're still lining up to kick from a similar angle as the no-step kick: you're inside the line of their front foot.

Comment: Great answer. Tony, you said *"After the jab-cross, I'd almost always throw another jab as I rotate back, ... kick without moving the back foot."* I am wondering why you would throw a 3rd punch (the second Jab after the Cross) that actually un-does the momentum and unloads the left leg (lead leg)? After throwing the Right handed Cross, our left side is loaded with power - we could choose to throw a left hook or a left/lead roundhouse with that stored up momentum. Throwing the second Jab after the Cross takes away all that built up momentum and energy, no?

Comment: @RoundHouse The second jab is used to keep them busy and distracted and as a "spacer" - measuring distance and preventing them getting close enough to punch you while you bring the kick around.  As such, you're not driving forward behind that jab, you're just turning back for the kick, but if they try to close to punch you they should walk into the jab.  There's a couple problems with throwing a hook instead: to get any power behind it - you'd have to step the back leg in toward the front foot to narrow the stance so the hips can rotate powerfully behind the hook, otherwise you'd be flailing

Comment: with something like a "reverse knife-hand" aka "ridge hand" or inner-forearm "collaring" attack rugby players sometimes use (illegally).  You'd also be very exposed if you left the back foot where it was during a hook.  The second problem is any contact your hook makes pushes the front side of your body in the opposite direction to the roundhouse, so you're taking power out of the rotation that powers your kick.

Comment: Thanks, Tony D. I think I may not have emphasize the nature of the step. It's not a big step. It's more of a natural tendency to shift the right hind leg when launch the front (loaded) left leg into the inner left thigh of the opponent. I find it harder to keep the rear right leg planted on the ground...(continued below)

Comment: ...(continued) It tends to at least shift positions, to facilitate the rightward swing of the left leg, and in so doing, tends to be launched in the direction of the rightward swing to enable more power. I was just told long ago (possibly in another context) that keeping the supporting leg on the ground ensures more power in a roundhouse, though I'm not sure about the biomechanics behind this.

Comment: @user2153235: in Thai boxing, a step with the back leg is often used to prime the hips for a more powerful front-foot kick.  For this particular combination, whether you need to step or not will be largely about adjusting the angle and distance based on where your opponent has got to during the punches.  Still, if the distances and angles are ok without stepping *and* your technique's good,  there's no particular reason to step the back foot.

Comment: Something to experiment with: try not to throw your weight fully on to the left leg during the cross: think of the cross as being powered by a rotation of the right hip forwards, and that hip rotation powered by the right leg - initially bent at a the knee - straighting against the floor.  If your centre of mass is about 65/35 between the left & right feet, you should have the ability to twist the hips powerfully back into the kick without needing a step to prime them.  If you transfer too much weight to the left foot, it'll be more of a struggle getting off it.

Comment: I come from a Shotokan background, where the cross is fully committed to. Trying to blend it with kickboxing, where rear leg is still bent. Sometimes, I do end up as you say, not fully on the left lead leg. I guess it's a matter of how the cross ends up. If you have the chance to really bring it home with an far-reaching cross, you'll be less ideally positioned to quickly follow up with a lead leg roundhouse to the inner thigh by simply rotating the hips. The hope is that you'll have connected (or at least forced opponent backward), thus allowing for the slower roundhouse. Thanks!

Comment: @user2153235: I fully agree - if you've really driven the cross through, then a back-leg kick is likely to be easier, faster and stronger than a front leg.  The whole jab-cross-[jab-]front-leg-kick thing is more about using the hands as setup for the kick, when you're not really trying to knock down with the hands.  (My background's an old-fashioned style of taekwondo/tangsoodo (I hate to say it, but for a famous reference point, Chuck Norris's style is similar), then a few years of hapkido, half a dozen kyokushin, a bit under a year of Thai boxing, and a few other things....)

Comment: Actually, my last comment was still about front leg roundhouse. But I do drill a combo where the back leg does the roundhouse, though it tends to be to the body.  It's jab, cross, hook, back-round; or jab, cross, back to ready stance for an instant, back-round. In the 2nd combo, the return to ready is more to reset the hips so that it launch the rear round, which is hard to do from a cross position unless you're round-housing low.  I get what you're saying about the arms being a setup for the kick.  And man, your background sounds very well rounded. P.S. What's wrong with Chuck, he's invincibl